# How to get the HTML of shown content in Webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, jsoup

For educational reasons I am learning about parsing and scrapping HTML content.
I saw a lot of questions and answers about retrieving the html content displayed in a webview.
My Problem is, that I am not able to get the whole html, how I suppose it should look like. When I inspect the URL in Safari all Items can be located in the HTML, but when I load the HTML of the same URL from webview there are missing items.
My code right now:
`

```
private WebView wv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    wv.addJavascriptInterface(new LoadListener(), "HTMLOUT");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if(wv.getProgress() == 100) {
                view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML(document.documentElement.innerHTML);");
            }
        }
    });


    wv.loadUrl("http://hdfilme.tv/movie-movies?order_f=view&order_d=desc&per_page=#");
}

class LoadListener{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void processHTML(String html) {
        longInfo(html);
    }
}

public static void longInfo(String str) {
    if (str.length() > 4000) {
        Log.i("DEBUG", str.substring(0, 4000));
        longInfo(str.substring(4000));
    } else
        Log.i("DEBUG", str);
}`
```

Usuallay I use Jsoup for connecting and parsing HTML, but in this case the webpage is using CloudFlare and I was not able to succesfully load the page HTML.

What I found out is that every Listitem of the webpage which includes the `<span class="hot"></span>` tag is not loaded in my code right now.

What am I missing ?

***UPDATE1***

The hint of F.Klein did it!

I really do not understand why setting the user agent as follows:
`wv.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 3.0; en-us; Xoom Build/HRI39) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.13");`

changed the retrieved HTML as I supposed it to be. The shown content in the webview was before and after setting the user agent the same.

***UPDATE2***

I have been to early pleased...changing the user agent ended up in missing items to show up but other items which were before loaded now are gone??? I don´t get the problem.

Comment: Have you tried setting a user agent? Default would be loading the mobile presentation, there might be differences in the versions.

Comment: No not yet, I will give it a try. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The items which are missing in the returned HTML are shown in the Webview, that is why I am so confused, but I will try setting a user agent.

Comment: `onPageFinished()` does not take AJAX into account, so you may be calling it before the entire content loads.

Comment: I tried with 5 seconds delay but that didn´t helped. The content which I am missing in the loaded HTML is already visible in the webview, hence this shouldn´t be the problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, even without setting the userAgent I get the elements with class=hot. On a side note: you should override shouldInterceptRequest in you WebViewClient and block most of the js files to avoid all those ads.

Comment: I have been to early pleased...changing the user agent ended up in missing items to show up but other items which were before loaded now are gone??? I don´t get the problem. @F.Klein are all of the listitems fetched in your case? And if yes, what could be the reason I am struggling with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously guessed, the mobile version of the page seems to be different from the default version: with the mobile version there are 50 `div`elements with the class `box-product`found while the default version finds 70 elements.

**Fix**

```
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36";
wv.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);
```

Your mentioned user-agent (Update 1) is one for the mobile version, hence the same result as without setting a user-agent (defaulting to mobile version on android).

---

**Alternative without WebView using [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Rhino) (to calculate the challenge to acquire the access cookie):**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new BackgroundTask().execute();

}

class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        scrapePage();
        return null;
    }
}

private void scrapePage() {

    Map<String, String> cookies;
    final String referrer = "http://hdfilme.tv/movie-movies?order_f=view&order_d=desc&per_page=0";

    try {

        Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://hdfilme.tv/movie-movies?order_f=view&order_d=desc&per_page=#")
                .followRedirects(true).header("Connection", "keep-alive").userAgent(userAgent)
                .ignoreHttpErrors(true).header("host", "hdfilme.tv").referrer(referrer).method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();

        cookies = res.cookies();

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(res.body());

        String[] scriptlines = doc.select("script").toString().split("\n");

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("var a={};");

        for (String line : scriptlines) {
            if (line.contains("var s,t,o,p,b,r,e,a,k,i,n,g")) {
                builder.append(line.trim());
                builder.append("t=\"hdfilme.tv\"");
            }
            if (line.contains("a.value = parseInt")) {
                builder.append(line.trim());
            }
        }

        int jschl_answer = runRhino(builder.toString());
        String jschl_vc = doc.select("input[name=jschl_vc]").first().attr("value");
        String pass = doc.select("input[name=pass]").first().attr("value");

        Log.e("info","Acquiring access cookies (takes about 4 seconds).");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000); //DDOS protection
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String requestUrl = "http://hdfilme.tv/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl";

        res = Jsoup.connect(requestUrl).followRedirects(true).userAgent(userAgent)
                .header("Referer", "http://hdfilme.tv/movie-movies?order_f=view&order_d=desc&per_page=")
                .data("jschl_vc", jschl_vc).ignoreHttpErrors(true).cookies(cookies)
                .data("jschl_answer", "" + jschl_answer).data("pass", pass).header("host", "hdfilme.tv")
                .method(Connection.Method.GET).timeout(5000).execute();

        Log.e("repsonse",res.statusCode() + " - " + res.statusMessage());

        cookies.putAll(res.cookies());

        builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("\tcookies");
        for (String cookie : cookies.keySet()) {
            builder.append("\n\t\t" + cookie + ":" + cookies.get(cookie));
        }

        Log.e("cookies", builder.toString());

        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://hdfilme.tv/movie-movies?order_f=view&order_d=desc&per_page=#")
                .cookies(cookies)
                .userAgent(userAgent)
                .timeout(10000).referrer(referrer).header("host", "hdfilme.tv").followRedirects(true).get();

        builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("elements");

        for (Element element : doc.select(selector)) {
            builder.append("\n"+element.select("a[href]").attr("abs:href"));
        }

        Log.e("elements","total number of elements="+doc.select(selector).size()+"\n"+builder.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private int runRhino(String jsSource) {
    Context rhino = Context.enter(); // org.mozilla.javascript.Context;

    // Turn off optimization to make Rhino Android compatible
    rhino.setOptimizationLevel(-1);

    Scriptable scope = rhino.initStandardObjects();
    rhino.evaluateString(scope, jsSource, "ScriptAPI", 1, null);

    NativeObject object = (NativeObject) scope.get("a", scope);
    return (int) ((Double) object.get("value") / 1);
}
```